# Delete item from js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array and I'm trying to delete a site from it but it's not working. I know the function is called because I have added an alert to it and it alerted.

I removed some functions from the post just to make it shorter. But I have one function that removes ites from the array and it works great. It's just deleting a site by siteid that doesn't work for some reason.

```
[
  {
    "siteId": "9843598",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "siteId": "89419111",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 1231654351,
        "title": "This is item 2",
        "qty": 1
      },
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
function deleteSite(quoteCart, siteId) {
  try {
    quoteCart = quoteCart.filter((site) => site.siteId !== siteId);
    console.log("Filtered array:", quoteCart); // Check the filtered array

    updateCartDisplay();
    openWindowWithArrayContents();
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in deleteSite:", error);
  }
}
```

If I pressed delete on site # 9843598 I would expect the

```
[
  {
    "siteId": "89419111",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      },
      {
        "catNum": 1231654351,
        "title": "This is item 2",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Playground
https://jsfiddle.net/Bigmuddyfoot/4v5w2nLa/

Comment: There's a lot of unrelated code, can you edit your question to narrow down where the delete action is

Comment: `deleteSite` also expects 2 arguments, not 1. You're only passing it one when you perform your click.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please be specific about what you expect to happen and what isn't happening. What does your `console.log()` show? And Stackoverflow's code formatting is notoriously terrible but please edit your question to make it readable. Also please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Phix code has been updated.

Comment: @NickParsons What do you mean?

Comment: @AndyRay There is no errors or anything in console.log() it simply just does not remove the item from the array.

Comment: @KellyHansen You had `deleteSite($(this).data('siteid'));` before, this just passes one argument, not two, which is what your `deleteSite` is expecting (a `quoteCart` and a `siteId`), I imagine this would cause errors though, something like "filter is not a function".

Comment: check the datatype of siteId which you passing to delete method.

Comment: @NickParsons I added a like to jsfiddle with my current code

Comment: @ManojPilania what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `deleteSite` function might not be updating the cart properly due to a scoping issue. When you're passing `quoteCart` into the `deleteSite` function, the modifications made inside the function are limited to the local scope. So, you could return the updated `quoteCart` from the `deleteSite` function and use that returned value.

Check the modified version:

```
function deleteSite(quoteCart, siteId) {
    try {
        // Remove the site with the specified siteId
        quoteCart = quoteCart.filter((site) => site.siteId !== siteId);
        console.log("Filtered array:", quoteCart); // Check the filtered array

        // If there's only one site left and it matches the siteId, clear the quoteCart
        if (quoteCart.length === 1 && parseInt(quoteCart[0].siteId) === siteId) {
            quoteCart = [];
        }

        return quoteCart; // Return the updated quoteCart
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in deleteSite:", error);
        return quoteCart; // Return the original quoteCart in case of an error
    }
}
```

And when calling the deleteSite function, update the quoteCart variable and refresh the display:

```
quoteCart = deleteSite(quoteCart, siteIdToDelete);
updateCartDisplay();
```

**[See this JS<>Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e9hx5La/)**

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to share your knowledge and providing a solution that was a game-changer for me.

And thank you everyone that added to this and gave suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, since your codes are unrelated, I wrote it this way so that you can implement it in your project. I hope it works for you.

```
const data = [
  {
    "siteId": "9843598",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "siteId": "89419111",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 1231654351,
        "title": "This is item 2",
        "qty": 1
      },
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "siteId": "9843598",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 3",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

function removeDuplicateSiteIds(data) {
  try {
    const seenSiteIds = new Set();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const siteId = data[i].siteId;

      if (seenSiteIds.has(siteId)) {
        // Duplicate siteId found, remove the item
        const removedItem = data.splice(i, 1)[0];
        i--; // Adjust the index as we removed an element
        console.log(`Removed duplicate siteId: ${siteId}`, removedItem);
      } else {
        seenSiteIds.add(siteId);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while removing duplicate siteIds:", error.message);
  }
}

// Example usage
console.log("Before removal:", data);

removeDuplicateSiteIds(data);

console.log("After removal:", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cart=[


{
    "siteId": "9843598",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "siteId": "89419111",
    "items": [
      {
        "catNum": 1231654351,
        "title": "This is item 2",
        "qty": 1
      },
      {
        "catNum": 9418956196,
        "title": "This is item 1",
        "qty": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
function deleteSite(quoteCart, siteId) {
  try {
    quoteCart = quoteCart.filter((site) => site.siteId !== siteId);
    console.log("Filtered array:", quoteCart); // Check the filtered array

    //updateCartDisplay();
    //openWindowWithArrayContents();
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in deleteSite:", error);
  }
}
deleteSite(cart, (89419111).toString())
```

Comment: Error in deleteSite: TypeError: quoteCart.filter is not a function
    at deleteSite (script.js:156:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:88:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.4.min.js:2:43184)
    at y.handle (jquery-3.6.4.min.js:2:41168)

Comment: plz check this fiddle and output in console. https://jsfiddle.net/manojpilania/1ry8tuns/3/

Comment: may be deleteSite function is conflicting, try to change the name of this function.

Comment: is this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think *filter()* is the wrong function to use. In order to remove items, you should use *splice()*. *splice()* also edits the original array, so you don't have to deal with a return value.

```
function deleteSite(quoteCart, siteId) {
  try {
    let index = quoteCart.findIndex((site) => site.siteId === siteId);
    if(index != -1) quoteCart.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("Filtered array:", quoteCart); // Check the filtered array

    updateCartDisplay();
    openWindowWithArrayContents();
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in deleteSite:", error);
  }
}
```